# supporting columns insertion in CMS system

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

As monitor resolutions go up we are left with more and more of horizontal space (width) and less vertical space (most monitory nowadays are 16:9 or 16:10, some even 21:9). As such we require the ability to make long texts more suited for greater width. Newspaper like columns are a growing trend.

How to support those in CMS? I currently have an implementation where text is being put inside s and those divs are then decorated with certain classes for instance the Blueprint CSS system ones (span-5, span-8, etc.)

This works but doesn't offer great user experience. Most RTEs can't display those or required that site CSS is linked in. This brings in all other classes and CSS settings which is not optimal.

I've also implemented the option for the user to create a TEXT content item, which typically holds only one piece of text (one column for instance) and user can add those dynamically to the page (just like adding/removing widgets). The problem with this solution is that almost every paragraph becomes its own text content item the result being that the number of those texts grows and becomes unmanagable.

Please post your options as answers. I am actually looking for quite a comprehensive and innovative way of doing this because neither of the CMSs I tried had this solved (DotNetNuke, BlogEngine.net, Ruby's Refinery CMS, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options available to you without resorting to server-side implementations.  Some browsers support a CSS3 directive to provide multiple columns.

```
#div {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Properties available via CSS are:

- ‘column-count’, to determine the number of columns into which the content of the element will flow.
- ‘column-width’, to describe the optimal width of each column.
- ‘column-gap’, to set the padding between columns.
- ‘column-rule’, to define a border between columns.

That's the easiest approach, but does not guarantee the same experience everywhere.  There are also JavaScript solutions which can create columns based on text.

Here as an example of one: http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/

So, my recommendation would be for a progressive enhancement approach.  Use CSS3 options if availble, JavaScript if not, and fall back to a single wide column otherwise.

More information: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css3multicolumn

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will keep an eye on this spec but as it is now it's not appropriate. IE9 doesn't support it, Firefox and Chrome support it only through the vendor specific properties but the rendering is weird (column are not vertically aligned).

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something that DotNetNuke can handle, especially with the changes coming in DNN 6.1. The changes are targeted a mobile devices, but that doesn't mean that you can't simply use that functionality to provide different views of content based on the width of the screen available.

Comment: would that be 6.01 Beta or which version should I download? Where can I see it in action?

Comment: Yes, the 6.1.0 beta would be the one to download, though it is a couple of weeks old now, I believe we're close to a release